# How to make a growing cloth animation

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]I need to make a veil that should start short and grow, then follow to the floor, and also have cloth animation. Any suggestion would be helpful.
The mesh wrapped around her is just for collision so don't mind it.

Comment: Hello, it's a bit vague, do you have a storyboard or some pictures?

Comment: There, I uploaded an image, hope it gives an idea

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 shapekeys, one with a short veil, one with a long one:

[image]

[image]

Give a *Cloth* simulation to your object, create a vertex group that will be your pin group, enable the *Dynamic Mesh* option so that it will take the shapekey animation into account:

[image]

Give *Collision* to the body and floor, animate the shapekeys of your veil:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, good sir, I will give this a try now.

Comment: To give you an update about it, I have succeeded in getting the desired results following your steps. Thank you very much.